# Monitoring two recorders with one pair of headphones

Tags: monitoring

I'm getting a second Sound Devices 702, but I obviously want to only use one pair of headphones for monitoring. I got really excited thinking that the [HX-3](http://www.sounddevices.com/products/hx3master.htm) would do the trick, but I need 4 input (two stereo ones).

Any suggestions as to what cheap-ish but good quality device would work? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat with 744 + 722 - the 744 lets me switch between inputs 1+2 and 3+4, but I've been physically unplugging & replugging to check between recorders, which is not ideal - there must be a DIY solution?

I googled & someone asked the same question on MeFi 
http://ask.metafilter.com/167454/Can-I-use-one-set-of-headphones-for-two-audio-sources

A cheap solution: 3 in 1 out headphone selector for US$16
http://gadget.brando.com/prod_detail.php?prod_id=00326

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm a little worried about the monitoring quality of the headphone selector. I found this: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/174329-REG/Rolls_MX28_MX28_Compact_Stereo_Line.html which would be perfect except it is not battery powered. I'll keep looking and let you know if I find anything suitable. Thanks. 