# How to connect stereo output to mono speaker?

Tags: mixer, monitoring, mono, y-cable

My mixer has 1/4" STEREO out L and R (+4 dbu) and music store sold me 1/4" male to male one ring (mono) cable so just want to check is this a right cable to connect with speaker?

I have only one speaker which has 1/4" connection so do I need 'Y' Cable to get better effects of L and R with my Yamaha MG10XU mixer if yes which 'Y' cable I need stereo or mono?

[image: Yamaha MG10XU]

Comment: What do you connect to it and how?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4646/opposite-of-a-y-cable

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one speaker, you will only be able to output mono sound.  Stereo sound requires two speakers.  By convention, you should use the left 1/4 in. output to run to your speaker and ensure that the PAN knobs are all moved to the left (since you aren't using the right output).  It is also worth noting that unless your speaker is powered, you will need an amplifier to run sound through the speaker.

Stereo only works with two speakers, but it doesn't really matter as you can do a mono mix just fine.  Stereo is useful for spreading out the apparent source of inputs, but it isn't by any means critical to making something sound good, just a helpful and optional tool.  Whenever you do decide to get another speaker, you'll be able to plug it in through the right output and then the pan knobs will determine how much of the output from each channel goes to either the left or right speaker.

Comment: I have often seen this convention of panning everything to one side when using a mono output; an explanation of why this is needed would help. An initial assumption would be that the left and right outputs are already separated so there is no need to pan. Is there a gain benefit or is it just to obviate how the system is configured?

Comment: The reason for my previous comment is future proofing, because down the road if you try to record a stereo output then you might end up with a slight annoyances with the the delivered file only having sound in one side.

Comment: @user30031 - it is to make sure that the input to the right channel of the stereo channels is not lost.  A stereo channel with pan set to center should send L to L and R to R.  Panning will move the R channel on the input to also be included on the L channel of the output.  Since this is for playback, recording doesn't seem to be an issue.  If it was, then you would want to wire things up differently and would need some more cables to combine the left and right outputs post-mixer.

Comment: Also, fun trivia, this is one of the big situations where the difference between pan and balance matters.  Pan moves input across channels.  Balance simply adjusts the relative volume of the L and R channel while keeping the signals distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Those outputs are actually mono. When combined they provide the desired stereo effect

You can use the cable to connect the L or R output to the speaker, yet need to be careful when using panning on the channel buses as this will effect volume in this situation

Answer (score 1):

You are not compelled to create a stereo mix if you can handle only a monaural output. Simply use the "PAN" controls on the inputs to send everything to the LEFT (or CENTER, etc.) and use just the LEFT output.

It is NOT recommended to use a Y-cable to combine the audio from several outputs. The guy at the music store was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the FX send output (and turn FX RTN to zero, not utilizing the internal effect section) in order to connect your Bose.  That way you can still produce a stereo headphone/monitoring mix while having the Bose act as a mono PA.

FX send appears to be post-fader, so the Bose mix will follow your main mix, just adjusted by the channels' FX send controls and ignoring pan.