# Mixing board output to single Bose L1 compact

Tags: mixing, stereo

How do I connect from a Yamaha MG10xu to a single Bose L1 compact using a TRS cable? Asked another way, do I have to buy another Bose L1 compact to play music? My problem is I can only seem to get mono sound.

Isn't combining stereo into a single PA speaker a common use case?

From a Yamaha MG10xu, I get a good stereo signal (I can pan to test).  Plugging the Bose into the headphone out gives a bad combination of the left and right signals.

A similar question was asked here, but not answered (the answer was mono output): [a link](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/how-to-connect-stereo-output-to-mono-speaker)

[image: a MG10xu]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect stereo output to mono speaker?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/how-to-connect-stereo-output-to-mono-speaker)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use Channel-2 on the Bose L1 Compact, as Channel-1 is dedicated for Mic.

As page 10 and 11 of the manual suggests, you do need 2 units for stereo sound.

> Asked another way, do I have to buy another Bose L1 compact to play
>   music?

No, you can "play music" but it will be "mono" or "single channel". You can do this by following the answers already given in the same [link](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/how-to-connect-stereo-output-to-mono-speaker) you provided in your post. In short, you `PAN` all channels of your mixer to `LEFT` and use the `LEFT output` to the Bose L1 Compact `Channel-2 input`.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a cable that has 2 TR on one end and 2 RCA on the other.

The 2 TR end of the cable goes into Stereo out on the mixer.  The 2 RCA end of the cable goes to the Bose L1 RCA in.  The L1 plays sound properly (but not in stereo).

No additional L1 needed. You can't use TRS cable I think, but you can get great sound out of the Bose L1.

Answer (score -1):

No answer. My friend swapped his Mackie active system for an L1. It seems bizarre to produce a mono PA system these days. One problem (apart from not getting stereo "main") is that effects on compact mixers often rely on stereo pan. I just think this is a bad idea. The only way to make it work effectively is have a mixer that has a mono switch, but who wants a mono sound these days?